# Laravel redirect to a named route with param returns status 200

Tags: redirect, laravel-5.8, http-status-code-200

I have the following named route with params, to which I want to redirect from a post request:

```
Route::get('/view-project-team/{project_request_id}', 'SinglePageController@viewProjectTeam')->name('view.project.team');
```

The controller where I handle the post request:

```
public function createProjectTeam(Request $request){
    try {
        $projectRequest = ProjectRequest::create(['project_title' => $request->projectTitle]);

        TeamMember::whereIn('email', $request->projectTeamEmails)
         ->update([
             'project_request_id' => $projectRequest->id 
         ]);
         $projectTeam = TeamMember::get();

    /*return response()->json( [
        'success'=> true,
        'projectRequestId' => $projectRequest->id
    ]);*/   

    return redirect()->route('view.project.team', ['project_request_id' => $projectRequest->id ]);

    } catch(\Exception $e){
        return ['success' => false, 'message' => 'project team creation failed'];
    }

}
```

And the response that I get:

In the network tab, I see **90** under **Name**, which obviously stands for the id and only when I hover over I see the full URL **http://team-management-tool.test/view-project-team/90**

It is so weird as it seems correct the way i use the redirect, no clue what can be the issue then?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: it should be a 302 redirect so that the URL it changes in the browser and I see the page, now I only get the page in the response.

Comment: Is your devtools showing full network history, not just the last request?

Comment: u are right that was partly the issue, my preserved log was unchecked, but still the URL does not change in the browser and I see the old home page when it loads the redirected page with 200 status.

Comment: In your question you say you see the correct new URL (like `view-project-team/90`) in devtools. But in your comment you say you're not seeing that in the browser?

Comment: yes, that is true and weird.

Comment: I think that my other route, the one that I perform the post request from is declared so: `Route::get('/{any}', 'SinglePageController@index')->where('any', '.*');` which has routes configured on the front-end could be the reson?

Comment: Yes, that will certainly conflict with every other route you have, as it matches everything!  You either need to put it last, at the bottom of your routes file, or make it more specific.

Comment: hmm...I had it already as last but it does not help, will try to make it more specific then

Comment: `.*` matches 0 or more characters, so it will match `/` as well as `/something`.  I don't know your requirements but maybe you can separate that into a single home route (`/` without a wildcard), and something else?  Do you need a wildcard route that matches everything?

Comment: I just meant to match the routes that I created on the front-end with the wild-card, but everything might be an overkill. I changed it to / without a wildcard just to try if it works but it doesn't, I really don't understand what is causing the issue then.

Comment: If you have a set of specific, known URLs, it is better to explicitly define those routes. list them out in your routes file.  Try removing this wildcard/home route while you're working on this redirect problem - once that is behaving as expected, add your route(s) back one by one and test to see if they are causing conflicts.